# ShowMaskOnFocus not working for input-mask in angular

Tags: angular, masking, input-mask

I am using input-mask library and wanted to implement masking for time format. Which will accept integer numbers in HH:mm format so used this as below

```
timeInputMask = createMask({
    mask: '[99:99]',
    showMaskOnFocus: true,
    showMaskOnHover:true
  });

<input maxlength="5" placeholder="__:__" [inputMask]="timeInputMask" />
```

After loading a textbox default masking is coming as "**:**" so its working fine.
Problem is - as soon as I click inside the textbox, the masking is hiding i.e. text box is blank. After starts typing number the mask appears again.

Do you know how can we make masking visible on focus of he textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i use https://github.com/ngneat/input-mask library.

*.html

```
<input maxlength="5" placeholder="HH:MM" [inputMask]="time" />
```

*.ts

```
time = createMask<Date>({
    alias:'datetime',
    inputFormat: 'HH:MM'
  });
```

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sp6w7d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Its working. Thanks you. One observation if we paste the correct formatted value in the textbox, text box value is still null. How ever if we type it manually its value is updates. Any clue why its not assigning pasted value?

Comment: @Oxygen we need to add formControl for input field. Please check below url
Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sp6w7d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: added fomcontrol same as but its not working. Somehow the satckblitz url shared by you its not loading the UI so cant test there

Comment: I tried with shared formControl url I can paste `1245` into it. It working fine.
Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ckyxrp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hi @Arunkumar - We wanted to use regex with inputmask. Can you pls answer on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72102795/how-to-add-date-regex-in-masking-using-input-mast-in-angular